# Can anyone help me with this Combination Function?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

EDIT: Let's say there's a combination lock on a safe, and there are 6 different rows of numbers, and each row has 100 possible values. How many possible answers could there be to unlock the safe?

I have 6 sets: A-F.

Each set can have 100 different values. So....

- A1-A100

  B1-B100

  C1-C100

  D1-D100

  E1-E100

  F1-F100

How many combinations can I make?

6(600-6) = 3,564 combinations? Seems low....

Comment: What do you mean by "combination"?

Comment: are the values distinct that would drop it even more etc. also does order matter if so it's a permutation question not a combination question.

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you are selecting?

Comment: Let's say I have a combination lock on a safe, and there are 6 different rows of numbers, and each row has 100 possible values. How many possible answers could there be to unlock the safe?

Answer (score 0):

We use the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

We have $100$ choices in row $A$.  For each of these $100$ choices, we have $100$ choices for row $B$.  Thus, there are $100 \cdot 100 = 100^2$ possible ways to select the numbers for rows $A$ and $B$.  For each of these $100^2$ choices, we have $100$ choices for row $C$.  Can you continue?

Comment: So the answer would be 100^6? 1 trillion?

Comment: That is correct.